# Yii2 страница с большим количеством форм и ajax

Tags: php, yii2, ооп, mvc

Изучаю yii2 и планирую переводить старый "проект" на рельсы ооп и фреймворка. Проект - пользовательская "база данных". Это регистрация клиентов, их обращений и заказов, внесение результатов и т.п. Крутится на локальном сервере и пользователей 10-15 человек.

Если взять, например, страницу регистрации, то она преставляет из себя несколько форм и множество разных пунктов меню\кнопок. И всё это работает без перезагрузки страницы. Всего 5 форм и около 20-25 ajax возможных действий. И тут возникает вопрос.

Допустим, что всё это выводится контроллером `SiteController`. Под все таблицы базы данных созданы соответствующие модели, установлены связи между ними. Вьюха тоже есть. Так вот. Получается, что все эти ajax и формы нужно принимать и обрабатывать одним контроллером `SiteController` в действии `actionIndex`? Или это как-то разносится на какие-то части и т.п.?

> В хорошо организованных приложениях контроллеры обычно очень тонкие и
>   содержат лишь несколько строк кода. Если ваш контроллер слишком
>   сложный, то обычно это означает, что вам надо провести его рефакторинг
>   и перенести часть кода в другие места [[исчточник]](https://yiiframework.com.ua/ru/doc/guide/2/structure-controllers/#best-practices).

Вопрос, собственно, в этом и заключается - при большом количестве форм и ajax на странице, где и как всё это обрабатывать? И вообще как быть, что посоветуете? Направьте, пожалуйста.

**Upd** Тут, наверное, вопрос больше касается структуры приложения. У меня база данных реляционная больше 40 таблиц. Понятно, что под каждую таблицы нужно будет создать модели, описать связи и т.п. Но.... В самом приложении у меня по сути 3 страницы основные - регистрация, внесение результатов и поиск. Если брать страницу "Регистрация", то там, как я уже писал, несколько форм и много разныx ajax. Например, форма регистрации нового клиента и полный CRUD аяксом для этой формы. Потом на той же странице форма для регистрации обращений этого клиента и т.д. По сути страница одна - registration. Получается, что и контроллер один - `RegistratonController`. А внутри множество экшенов: `actionAddClient`, `actionUpdateClient`, `actionDeleteClient`, `actionLoadClient`, `actionAddHandling` и т.п. Аяксом я обращаюсь к нужному экшену, где произвожу действия, использую модель и др.
На странице поиска (это уже контроллер `SearchController`) выполняются строго заданные запросы - например, сколько клиентов без того-то и того-то и информация о них. И там тоже свои action. Но по сути-то это дублирование кода - если я на странице регистрации получаю информацию о клиентах и вывожу их в одном виде, а на странице поиска я также получаю информацию о клиентах, но уже немного в другом виде и с некоторым дополнительным условием... Словом, как тут быть? И верно ли я всё понимаю?

Comment: Все запросы без проблем могут приходить на один контроллер. Кстати я тоже занимаюсь переносом кода на фреймворк и рекомендую Symfony3. Там можно создавать "бандлы" то есть один контроллер в бандле будет обрабатывать одни запросы аякс, а другой бандл будет обрабатывать другие со своим контроллером (GET запросы страниц). Уж очень мне нравится Symfony в этом плане ИМХО.

Comment: Тонкий контроллер не означает, что сам сам контроллер должен быть предельно мал, а вот действия в нём (actions) должны содержать минимум логики приложения, их задача получить параметры запроса и использовать модель (model) и представление (view) для реализации необходимого действия. В том, что в контроллере будет описано много действий, ничего страшного нет.

Comment: @Blacknife Спасибо за ответ. Я дополнил вопрос.

Comment: @n.osennij если избегать повторения кода, то в контроллерах можно использовать трейты, они там будут работать также как и в любых других классах, либо можно использовать [standalone actions](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-controllers.html#standalone-actions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно я не совсем корректно понял, но. Если у вас есть по сути повторяющиеся методы в контроллерах (экшены) и все работает с таблицами пользователей, при этом поиск работает с фильтрами на существующие таблицы пользователей, то отдельные контроллеры создавать не нужно. Вам попросту необходимо добавлять фильтр через ORM для реализации поиска. И любые CRUD операции работающие как с общими данными так и с фильтрованными поиском данными будут применяться на соответствующие данные пришедшие из дата-провайдера. А уже содержимое дата-провайдера зависит от контекста (поиск или любой другой результат).
Резюмируя:
Если источник данных один, то нет необходимости изобретать кучу контроллеров. Есть необходимость исключительно в гибкой реализации обработки некоторых методов, но отнюдь не новых контроллеров. Основываться на принципе: источник данных один - контроллер один. Под источником данных я имею ввиду некий объект системы, что представляет собой одну или несколько связанных моделей необходимых для реализации процесса.

Comment: А как это будет выглядеть? Ну вот, допустим, две страницы приложения и два контроллера RegistrationController и SearchController. В первом CRUD данных и, как пример, получение информации о конкретном заказе пользователя: чтение данных о пользователе, о его обращении и заказе - три таблицы БД с условиями. Во втором контроллере мне также по сути нужно получить почти те же данные (исключая данные о клиенте), но уже не список обращений одного клиента, а список этих обращений за период. И при выборе одного подгружать отдельно данные о заказе. Т.е. как бы данные одни, но условия слишком разнятся.

Answer (score 1):

Делайте несколько `action` в контроллере `site`. Затем, используя [Yii-2 Pjax](https://nix-tips.ru/yii2-vnikaem-v-pjax.html), строите сайт как обычно, но из-за использования `Pjax` создастся иллюзия, как будто страница сайта не перезагружается, но при этом будет несколько независимых `action` в контроллере. Думаю это как раз то что Вам нужно.